# preg_match_all Multiple matches on same line

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a script which add a redirection page for external URLs

```
    // Do we have links?
    if (preg_match_all("/(\<a href=\")(.*)(\<\/a\>)/i", $message, $matches))
    {
        // Build local addresses and initialise replace arrays
        $localdomains = ($vbulletin->options['mh_anolink_localaddresses'] ? explode(" ", $vbulletin->options['mh_anolink_localaddresses']) : ($vbulletin->options['cookiedomain'] ? array($vbulletin->options['cookiedomain']) : array($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])));
        $preg_search = array();
        $preg_replace = array();
        $wb_list_checked = array();

        foreach ($matches[0] AS $key=>$fulllink)
        {
            preg_match("/(\<a href=\")(.[^\"]*)/i", $fulllink, $matches2);
            $serverurl = $matches2[2];
```

https://eval.in/389389

When it compares URLs in different lines, it works as expected adding the redirection URL:

```
http://serverfault.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Result:

```
http://www.sampleurl.com/redirect-to/?http://serverfault.com/
http://www.sampleurl.com/redirect-to/?http://stackoverflow.com/
```

However when there are several URLs in same line the redirect URL is added to the first URL only:

```
http://serverfault.com http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Result:

```
http://www.sampleurl.com/redirect-to/?serverfault.com http://stackoverflow.com/
```

How can I make sure all matches are replaced, regardless of new lines?

Thank you.

Comment: try "/(\<a href=\")(.*?)(\<\/a\>)/i, disable greedy

Comment: use option `U` - https://www.regex101.com/r/zA4oB9/1

Comment: What about `<a href="(.*?)">.*?<\/a>`? `<` and `>` aren't special regex characters so they don't need to be escaped. This will give you the linked resource as `$matches[1]`. It also might be worth looking at using an HTML /XML parser for this.